# Div and problem locating their CSS files

Tags: theming, nodes

I'm making my first website with drupal 8 for a university project.

I currently have 2 problems unresolved, the first one is that using the geolocation module to add a google map location is giving me problems, the width is setted at 50% and i can't find the way to change it to 100%, since I can't find the .css file that generate the style from the location page. The code from website that I think responsible is:

```
<div class="geolocation-google-map geolocation-processed" style="height: 400px; width: 50%; position: relative; overflow: hidden;>
```

but I don´t know how to change it.

The second problem I have is that just over, it generate a div ("<"div">" Location "<"/div">") with the label title, and I would like to add a .css class to hide, or simply remove it.

PS: I don't know if it's important, but I'm also using drupal 8 zymphonies theme.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Assuming you already have sub-themed Zymphonies theme, just add this in your sub-theme's stylesheet-

```
.geolocation-google-map {
width: 100% !important; }
```

If not, read this [documentation on sub-theming](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/creating-a-drupal-8-sub-theme-or-sub-theme-of-sub-theme) and do the above. Same goes for (2)

2) You can target your div (without class or id) using [:nth-child() selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)

Being a title, it usually is 1st or 2nd child of the view wrapper.If so

```
.view-name > div:nth-child(1) {
  //styles for a div that is the first child
}

.view-name > div:nth-child(2) {
  //styles for a div that is the second child
}`
```

Note that the div you're targeting has to be the direct child of its predecessor

Comment: Sorry for the delay I was a little busy.

I created the subtheme with you link and it worked
Thank yo very much.